# top right submatrix of a matrix in reduced row echelon form

Tags: matrices

In linear algebra, I remember that there was something special about the submatrix in the top right of an rref'd matrix.

```
1 0 0 |  0 1
0 1 0 | -1 0
0 0 1 |  1 0
-------------
0 0 0    0 0
```

You would ammend an identity matrix (in this case $2\times2$) above the submatrix and get two vectors in 5 dimensions. I think they say something about the kernel or so, but I do not really remember.

What do those two vectors tell me about the original matrix?

Comment: @Michael: It seems you accidentally entered "spelling" as a tag instead of an edit summary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you mean this: If you negate that submatrix and add the identity matrix *below* it, you get a basis for the kernel. In your example, you can choose $x_4$ and $x_5$ arbitrarily, and then a general element of the kernel is

$$x_4\pmatrix{0\\1\\-1\\1\\0}+x_5\pmatrix{-1\\0\\0\\0\\1}\;.$$

Comment: Yeah, that is the basis of the kernel that I got out of it per hand. Thanks!